# Merging Two Separate React Apps into one

Tags: reactjs

I have built two Reactjs applications separately. I would like to incorporate one of them into the other using react-router-dom Route as

```
<Route exact path="/app2" component={App2}/>
```

where App2 is imported in the main App. What I did is I included the second App in a folder in the first App. I copied from the second project only App2.js, components folder, context folder, and made sure all the packages I used for App2 is included in App1. But it didn't work. When I click the link which is supposed to take me to App2

```
<Link to="/app2">App2</Link>
```

doesn't work, and I stay in the home path "/". Are there any special considerations I need to take into account in this case?

Comment: I found the problem. There were no special consideration, but the mistake I made was I didn't include route to the home page. It doesn't work without a route to the home page first before any other route.